# Single Sign on using Authentication Cookie between ASP.net Framework and Core 2

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, cookies, asp.net-identity

We have a series of applications that use single sign on via a shared ASP Identity Authentication cookie. These applications are MVC applications built in Framework 4.6.1. All the applications are on the same domain, so setting the cookie domain allows us to achieve single sign on.

We are researching the possibility of adding a new application using .net core 3. I understand that there is documentation to set up shared cookies between Framework and Core found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cookie-sharing?view=aspnetcore-2.2)

I have tried to follow this guide, but I am unable to see the cookie be picked up by the new Core application.

Framework Sartup.Auth found here

```
namespace Authentication
{
    public partial class Startup
    {


    private static void ApplyRedirect(CookieApplyRedirectContext context)
    {
        Uri absoluteUri;
        if (Uri.TryCreate(context.RedirectUri, UriKind.Absolute, out absoluteUri))
        {
            var path = PathString.FromUriComponent(absoluteUri);
            if (path == context.OwinContext.Request.PathBase + context.Options.LoginPath)
            {
                context.RedirectUri = AppLocator.GetAppBaseUrl(AppType.Net) + "/Account/Account/Login" +
                    new QueryString(
                        context.Options.ReturnUrlParameter,
                        context.Request.Uri.AbsoluteUri);
            }
        }

        context.Response.Redirect(context.RedirectUri);
    }

    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {

        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            CookieName = ".AspNet.SharedCookie",
            CookieDomain = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CookieDomain"],
            AuthenticationType = "Identity.Application",
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
            LogoutPath = new PathString("/Account/Logout"),
            Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
            {
                // Enables the application to validate the security stamp when the user logs in.
                // This is a security feature which is used when you change a password or add an external login to your account.  
                OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, User, int>(
                    validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
                    regenerateIdentityCallback: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager),
                    getUserIdCallback: (id) => (id.GetUserId<int>())),
                OnApplyRedirect = ApplyRedirect
            },
            ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(ApplicationConfiguration.GetCookieSessionTimoutInMinutes()),
            SlidingExpiration = true,

            TicketDataFormat = new AspNetTicketDataFormat(
                                    new DataProtectorShim(
                                        DataProtectionProvider.Create(new DirectoryInfo(@"c:\shared-auth-ticket-keys\"), (builder) => { builder.SetApplicationName("SharedCookieApp"); })
                                        .CreateProtector("Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies." +
                "CookieAuthenticationMiddleware",
             "Identity.Application",
            "v2")))
        });

}
```

I have setup the new DataProtection provider, and sing on is working in this application.
Setup for the new Core App

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

namespace IdentityTest
{
    public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {
            // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
            options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
        });


        services.AddControllersWithViews();
        services.AddRazorPages();

        services.AddDataProtection()
            .PersistKeysToFileSystem(new DirectoryInfo(@"c:\shared-auth-ticket-keys\"))
            .SetApplicationName("SharedCookieApp");

        services.AddAuthentication("Identity.Application").AddCookie("Identity.Application",options=>
            {
                options.Cookie.Name = ".AspNet.SharedCookie";
                options.Cookie.Domain = "";
                options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None;
                options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.None;
                options.DataProtectionProvider = DataProtectionProvider.Create(new DirectoryInfo(@"c:\shared-auth-ticket-keys\")).CreateProtector("Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies." +
                "CookieAuthenticationMiddleware",
             "Identity.Application",
            "v2");
            });

        //services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options => {
        //    options.Cookie.Name = ".AspNet.SharedCookie";
        //});

    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        var cookiePolicyOptions = new CookiePolicyOptions
        {
            MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None,
            Secure = CookieSecurePolicy.None
        };

        app.UseCookiePolicy(cookiePolicyOptions);

        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseAuthentication();

        app.UseAuthorization();



        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            endpoints.MapRazorPages();
        });
    }
}
}
```

When I try to navigate to an authorised controller I see the following output in my application

```
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.DefaultAuthorizationService[2]
  Authorization failed.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler[12]
 AuthenticationScheme: Identity.Application was challenged.
```

So it seems to be trying to authorise using the correct method, but not picking up the cookie that should be shared across applications. Claims Identity not being created and user not being shown as authenticated.

Has anyone successfully produced a shared cookie across framework and core 2/3 applications. Are there any gotchas I am missing. I wondered if it is because I am working with Framework identity going to Core rather than the other way round. But any help or insight would be appreciated.